# Advanced Data import into SQL server

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, ssis

I have banged my head against the wall long enough.  I am fairly new to database management in my new job and am struggling with a complex import into a tsql database from an excel file.  Here's a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a raw data file with student assessment scores.  Lets say it looks something like this, with a couple of example records:

```
Student Name,  State ID, Test Discipline, Test Score, Test Subscore 1, Test subsubscore 1, Test subsubscore 2, etc...

Sam Smith,     11111,    Reading,         250,        95,              73

Sam Smith,     11111,    Mathematics,     275,        75,              85

John Anderson, 11112,    Reading,         375,        65,              78

John Anderson, 11112,    Mathematics      340,        87,              77
```

I have a table (test) on the database that has the following information on the tests:

```
testID (PK), parentID (FK), Test Name,           Discipline (varchar), Allow Score (bit) and some other information

1000,        null,          Reading Overall,     Reading,             1

1001,        1000,          Literacy,            Reading,             1

1002,        1000,          Comprehension,       Reading,             1

1003,        null,          Mathematics Overall, Math,                1

1004,        1003,          Fractions,           Math,                1

1005,        1003,          Geometry,            Math,                1
```

I need to insert the test scores into a table (testscore) with the following columns.
scoreID (PK), parentID (FK), testID(FK), personID (FK), score int

I need the records from the raw data file transferred into the testscore table as follows. (I assigned a starting scoreID, but I need to reference the max scoreID found in the table so the starting value is one larger.)  Note, the personID is not the same as the stateID in the raw data file.  It is a primary key of the person, but I'm thinking I can inner join them.  Note the parent/child relationship in the score records also...I don't know how to get them to relate.

```
scoreID, parentID, testID, personID, score

2000,    null,     1000,   501,      250

2001,    2000,     1001,   501,      95

2002,    2000,     1002,   501,      73

2003,    null,     1004,   501,      275

2004,    2003,     1005,   501,      75

2005,    2003,     1006,   501,      85

2006,    null,     1000,   523,      375

2007,    2006,     1001,   523,      65

2008,    2006,     1002,   523,      78

2009,    null,     1004,   523,      340

2010,    2009,     1005,   523,      87

2011,    2009,     1006,   523,      77
```

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What tool are you using to import? I suggest you first import the data into a staging table and think about what update statements you need to populate fields in the staging table, then apply that staging table to your final table.

Comment: Why do you need a parent field for the test scores?  You can figure out the parent by join to the test table on testID.  What do you ultimately want to do with the data?  Are you creating a report?  If so what do you want the report to look like?

Comment: I have tried creating several temporary tables, separating the data into them, and then inserting them one at a time, but the problem is that I need to iterate this through about 600 different test names.  Also I don't know how to lookup the primary key for the testID from another table.   I need the parent ID for the test scores because the website teachers use to view the scores shows all child scores for the parent test on one page.  I need to maintain this parent/child relationship.

Comment: Also - sorry for the delay.  I was sidetracked onto other projects.